# A stricter condition of Dini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

I am trying to do a similar proof of Dini's Theorem but with a stricter condition. So, given $f: X \to Y$, where *(X, d)* and *(Y, d')* are metric spaces, and

1. X is compact
2. $f_n \to f$ pointwisely
3. $d'(f(x), f_n(x)) \le 2*d'(f(x), f_m(x))$ for all $m, n \in N$ with $n \ge m$
4. $f_n$ and *f* are continuous

So (3) is given instead of the monotonicity of sequence $(f_n)$. I want to show in this case $f_n$ also converges to *f* uniformly.

Attempt:
I am trying to establish an open covering $(A_n^\epsilon$) similar to what is in Dini's Theorem: $A_n^\epsilon=\{d'(f(x),f_n(x))<\epsilon\}$, and then I can have $A_n^\epsilon \subset A_{n+1}^\epsilon$ so that $(A_n^\epsilon)$ forms an open covering of *X*. Then since *X* is compact, there is a sub-covering of $(A_n^\epsilon)$ such that all $x \in X$ are in some $A_n^\epsilon$.

But I am struggling to find such appropriate open covering of *X*. I tried to let $A_n^\epsilon=\{d'(f(x),f_n(x))<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\}$ but condition (3) doesn't lead to $A_n^\epsilon \subset A_{n+1}^\epsilon$ as it does in Dini's Theorem.

Can someone please have a look?  Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a stricter condition but a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some $e>0.$ For each $x\in X$

take $m_x \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall m\ge m_x\,[\,d'(f_m(x),f(x))<e/6\,]$

and take $r_x>0$ such that $d'(f_{m_x}(x), f_{m_x}(z))<e/6$ and $d'(f(x),f(z))<e/6$ for every $z$ in the open ball $B_d(x,r_x).$

Observe that if $n\ge m_x$ and $z\in B_d(x,r_x)$ then $$d'(f_n(z),f(z))\le 2d'(f_{m_x}(z),f(z))\le$$ $$\le 2d'(f_{m_x}(z), f_{m_x}(x))+2d'(f_{m_x}(x),f(x))+2d'(f(x),f(z))<e.$$ Now as $X$ is compact, take a finite $S\subset X$ such that $X=\cup_{x\in S}B_d(x,r_x)$ and let $M=\max\{m_x: x\in S\}.$

Any $z\in X $ belongs to $B_d(x,r_x)$ for some $x\in S$, and $M\ge m_x$ when $x\in S,$ so $$\forall z\in X\, \forall n\ge M\,[\,d'(f_n(z),f(z))<e\,].$$

Comment: This, and the original Dini Theorem, apply for any compact space $X$. Just replace $B_d(x,r_x)$ in the proof with "some nbhd of $x$". The original Dini Theorem is presented in R. Engelking's General Topology as a preliminary step in a remarkably brief proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.