# A case where pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

i was wondering if i might be able to get help with the following question:

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces with $X$ compact. 
>   Let $f_n$ and $f$ be continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ and suppose that 
>   $f_n\to f$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$. Show that if there is a constant $N$
>   such that
>   $$ \rho(f(x),f_n(x)) \le N \rho(f(x),f_m(x)) \quad\mbox {for all $m,n$ natural numbers with  $n\ge m$,} $$
>   then $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Comment: I guess this would be a generalization of Dini's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem): for monotone real sequences, we'd have $N=1$. Probably, the proof of said theorem can be modified accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682925/a-stricter-condition-of-dinis-theorem/3683006#3683006